# Capistrano on Windows: 'cap deploy' defaults to wrong username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I am trying to use Capistrano to connect over ssh with svn in order to deploy an app to prod from a windows dev box (Aptana Studio Community Edition). When I run 'cap deploy' it starts executing tasks in deploy.rb, then it asks for a password for user account 'a' but I need to connect using account 'b' not 'a'. User account 'a' has no root privileges on the linux box that I am trying to connect. It seems that svn picks up a default username.

Does any know what's going on? is svn picking up Windows username? in deploy.rb i tell it to connect with user account 'b' with password 'bb'.

Comment: one more thing, what has been the experience you have had setting-up/using Capistrano for a RoR project from a Windows based development environment?????

Comment: Can you show some of your configuration?

Comment: Agree with @slillibri. I'll need to see your deploy.rb before I can give you advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capistrano on Windows is a huge pain in the neck. I only moved back to it when I shifted my development environment to Linux.

Anyway, here's some things to try...

1. If you enter a blank password, does it prompt for a username?
2. I'm unclear whether it is the svn or shell username that's wrong but either way you can use these in your deploy.rb file:

   set :scm_username, "your svn username"

   set :scm_password, "your svn password"

   set :user, "your linux user"

Comment: thanks. i was missing: set :user, "your linux user"

nm about svn. has nothing to do with it.